# Change default font roFontRegistry in Roku

Tags: fonts, roku, brightscript

I have created a page with   roImageCanvas ,and i am trying to change its default font with another one.bellow is my code but this won't work.Please help me to resolve this error.thanks in advance.

```
 canvas = CreateObject("roImageCanvas")    
 port = CreateObject("roMessagePort")
 canvas.SetMessagePort(port)
 items = []

FontInterface=CreateObject("roFontRegistry") 'create global font access
Fontinterface.Register("pkg:/source/Univers.ttf")
Font=FontInterface.GetFont("Univers",36,false,false)
FontSmall=FontInterface.GetFont("Univers",15,false,false)


items.Push({
Text: "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s"
TextAttrs:{ font: Font, color: "#a0a0a0"}
TargetRect: {x: 200, y: 75, w: 300, h: 500}
})

items.Push({
Text: "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s"
TextAttrs:{ font: FontSmall, color: "#a0a0a0"}
TargetRect: {x: 600, y: 75, w: 300, h: 500}
})

canvas.SetLayer(0, { Color: "#00ff00", CompositionMode: "Source" })
canvas.SetLayer(1, items)
canvas.Show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
Font=FontInterface.Get("Univers",36,false,false)
FontSmall=FontInterface.Get("Univers",15,false,false)
```

Insted of

```
Font=FontInterface.GetFont("Univers",36,false,false)
FontSmall=FontInterface.GetFont("Univers",15,false,false)
```

Answer (score 1):

First, for the roImageCanvas, you should be using [roFontRegistry.Get()](http://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/ifFontRegistry#ifFontRegistry-GetfamilyasStringsizeasIntegerboldasBooleanitalicasBooleanasString) instead of [roFontRegistry.GetFont()](http://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/ifFontRegistry#ifFontRegistry-GetFontfamilyasStringsizeasIntegerboldasBooleanitalicasBooleanasObject).  GetFont() is for use with the roScreen.

Second, are you sure the font family is actually "Univers"?  After you've registered the font, you can call [roFontRegistry.GetFamilies()](http://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/ifFontRegistry#ifFontRegistry-GetFamiliesasObject) to get a list of the registered font family names.